# how to animate + symbol to disappear on table cell

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uitableview

i have an table view and + symbol is on the every cell of table view ,i should able  to see disappearing + symbol by animating  whenever i selected the cell [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fade out the plus symbol when its clicked? If so you can do it by animating its alpha to 0 like so:

```
[UIView beginAnimation:nil]
[mySymbol setAlpha:0.0]
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.33]
[UIView commitAnimation];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i hav added that image as a subview to table view ,how to remove from cell

Answer (score 0):

The question does nor really include enough information to know if this is a good answer or not, but I'll give it a shot.

Create a css class so that the plus sign is included as an image background for the un-animated element. Have another css class that DOES NOT include the plus sign in the image background.

As part of your "animation javascript", add something along these lines:

```
element.className = "noPlusSignClass";
```

and of course, your "unanimation javascript" would include something like this:

```
element.className = "plusSignClass";
```

Hope this helps.